# Python minesweeper count adjacent mines bug

Tags: python, list, 2d

I am in the process of coding a minesweeper game on python. I am having trouble with my countAdjacentMines function in python. I am trying to count the number of mines around a given cell in a 2d list like this:

```
L = [
['','',''],
['x','',''],
['x','','']
]
```

When I try to run my code for row 1 column 2, I should get 1 as there is only 1 mine in the 3x3 around row 1 column 2, but my function returns 2. How do I go around the fact that when python 2d Lists get a value like L[-1][1] the -1 just doesnt count anything instead of the len(lis)-1 position?

heres my code:

```
def countAdjacentMines(lis,row,col):
    total = 0
        try: 
            if lis[row-1][col-1] == 'x':
                total+=1
        except IndexError:
            pass               
        try: 
            if lis[row-1][col] == 'x':
                total+=1
        except:
            pass
        try: 
            if lis[row-1][col+1] == 'x':
                total+=1
        except:
            pass
        try: 
            if lis[row][col-1] == 'x':
                total+=1
        except:
            pass
        try: 
            if lis[row][col+1] == 'x':
                total+=1
        except:
            pass
        try: 
            if lis[row+1][col-1] == 'x':
                total+=1
        except:
            pass
        try: 
            if lis[row+1][col] == 'x':
                total+=1
        except:
            pass
        try: 
            if lis[row+1][col+1] == 'x':
                total+=1
        except:
            pass
        return total

L = [
['','',''],
['x','',''],
['x','','']
]

print(countAdjacentMines(L,0,1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I understand the question but if I did correctly, you want python to not go to the last row because of index -1 in the list?

If so, try using a max function like this!

```
L[max(0,row-1)][1]
```

EDIT:
My old solution was bogus and counted the cells you wanted to ignore so I removed it. Instead,what you could do is add an and to your if where appropriate like so

```
def countAdjacentMines(lis,row,col):
    total = 0        
    if ((row > 0 and col > 0) and lis[row-1][col-1] == 'x'):
        total+=1               
    if  (row > 0 and lis[row-1][col] == 'x'):
        print("here")
        total+=1
    if ((row > 0 and col < len(lis)-1) and lis[row-1][col+1] == 'x'):
        total+=1
    if (col > 0 and lis[row][col-1] == 'x'):
        total+=1 
    if (col < len(lis)-1 and lis[row][col+1] == 'x'):
        total+=1
    if ((row < len(lis)-1 and col > 0) and lis[row+1][col-1] == 'x'):
        total+=1
    if (row < len(lis)-1 and lis[row+1][col] == 'x'):
        total+=1
    if ((row < len(lis)-1 and col < len(lis)-1) and lis[row+1][col+1] == 'x'):
        total+=1
    return total

L = [
['','',''],
['x','',''],
['x','','']
]
```

This will work so long as you have a square matrix, otherwise, you can use len(lis[row]) or something similar.

Also, I suggest finding another way than try except pass to handle errors.

Fourth time's the charm?

LAST EDIT: if you do countAdjacentMines(L,2,0) it outputs 1 because there's no case to count the current cell we're on as it is now.

Comment: That is absolutely what I need, could you just explain how do use the line of code? Not quite sure I understand

Comment: Very good explanation, when I tried using the max function it made it so it would go to the largest value, in my case I don't ever want a negative column or row index because it messes the minesweeper function and the max always chooses the 0 over the negative, what I'm trying to do is just not factor in negative rows or columns, any way to do this? i.e in a corner of a minesweeper game, we dont look at the rows and columns not involved

Comment: @Kamal if this works for you, please consider accepting answer ^.^ Otherwise let me know what's wrong, I'll gladly help!